# How to read excel data in Laravel?

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I am trying to read data from excel and import into my database. i tried reading it using
 `dd()` but am seeing some horrible things which isn't the actual data in the excel. dont know if there is something i have to do. I need help.

this is what i have done so far

```
        public function import_results(Request $request)
        {

           $this->validate($request,[

            'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,xls,xlsx'
           ]);

            $file = file($request->file->getRealPath());
            dd($file);

       }
```

afterwards  this is what i see which isn't the data in the excel Sheet

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You **are** reading the Excel spreadsheet, if you were to open an excel spreadsheet in notepad, that's how it'd look.

In order to interpret the file, you'll need to use a library. The one I'm currently using in my projects is [PHPSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet).

Comment: how can i use it. i have just install using ```composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet``` and imported ```require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;``` in my controller but am still seeing the same thing

Comment: That depends on your implementation. Definitely have a read of [the docs](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Can you please supply more information of how to integrate it with Laravel?
The [Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) wrapper does not support `load` method anymore.

Comment: @guyaloni I use PHPSpreadsheet without a wrapper. There are plenty of [examples in the docs](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score -1):

add your controller

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

and use this method

```
public function postUploadCsv()
{
    $rules = array(
        'file' => 'required',
        'num_records' => 'required',
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    // process the form
    if ($validator->fails()) 
    {
        return Redirect::to('customer-upload')->withErrors($validator);
    }
    else 
    {
        try {
            Excel::load(Input::file('file'), function ($reader) {

                foreach ($reader->toArray() as $row) {
                    User::firstOrCreate($row);
                }
            });
            \Session::flash('success', 'Users uploaded successfully.');
            return redirect(route('users.index'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \Session::flash('error', $e->getMessage());
            return redirect(route('users.index'));
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Looks like current version of Maatwebsite Excel does not support `load` method anymore.

Comment: all to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::load()